# Need help with UIText

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to make it so that the text displays like

Alabama
Alaska
Arkansas
and so on.

I mostly just need help on how to make it go to the next line of text

```
lblText.text = @"Alabama:";
```

i tried doing @"Alabama:"
              @"alaska:";

but it didn't work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Use UITextView

```
UITextView *textView;
.......
textView.text = @"Alabama \nAlaska \nArkansas";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `UITextView` as recommended, you can continue to use your `UILabel` and set `lblText.numberOfLines = 0;` to make it multiline.

You'll still need to take the previous advice and put a \n between each State Name.